# CMake cannot find header file near the source one

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake, clion

I don't want to install sqlite globally in my system, so I have downloaded the sqlite3 files from https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-amalgamation-3240000.zip and have copied `sqlite3.c` and sqlite3.h into the project folder.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(learn_cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(learn_cpp main.cpp)
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting any of the functions from `sqlite3.h` as suggestion in the CLion IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, CMake doesn't search headers files in the current directory. For enable this behaviour, set [CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html) variable:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_executable(learn_cpp main.cpp ...)
```